# Shall we run a goroutine for every async request, even when they are spawned from each other?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm developing a web application in go and I know in http package, every request is run in a separate goroutine. Now, if the code inside this goroutine queries a database then wait and using db result calls a remote api to fetch some related data and son on and so forth, shall I run each of these calls in separate goroutine or the one provided by http is enough?

Comment: Goroutines are cheap. Make separate goroutines for things you want to run in parallel, otherwise make it sequential.

Comment: the one provided by http is enough

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you're doing.

Each HTTP request should be handled *sequentially*.  That is to say, you shouldn't fire off a goroutine for handling the request itself:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    go func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // There's no advantage to this
    }(w,r)
}
```

However, there are still times when goroutines make sense when handling an HTTP response.  The two most common situations are probably:

1. You want to do something in parallel.

   ```
   func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
       wg.Add(2)
       go func() {
           defer wg.Done()
           /* query a remote API */
       }()
       go func() {
           defer wg.Done()
           /* query a database */
       }()
       wg.Wait()
       // finish handling the response
   }
   ```
2. You want to finish handling something *after* responding to the HTTP request, so that the web client doesn't have to wait.

   ```
   func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       // handle request
       w.Write( ... )
       go func() {
           // Log the request, and send an email
       }()
   }
   ```

Comment: quoting [this post](https://blog.golang.org/context), it seems that in order to use context facilities we shall run each call to db etc. in separate goroutine.

Comment: @JavadM.Amiri: Using context can be another reason to run things in a goroutine, but I don't know why you need a separate goroutine for every query.